# Permissions required to use Move-VM remotely in Hyper-v 2016

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I am attempting to run the PowerShell command "move-vm" remotely but I am getting permissions errors that I can't seem to get past.

My move-vm command looks like this:

```
move-vm -ComputerName SorceHost -Name $vm.name -DestinationHost $DestHost -IncludeStorage -DestinationStoragePath d:\vms -DestinationCredential $cred -Credential $cred
```

and I am defining the credentials like this

```
$username = ".\PSAPIUser"
$password = Get-Content 'C:\key\PSAPIAUTH.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -argumentlist $username, $password
```

Both the source and destination are on the same AD domain, and I have created a domain admin account specifically for this function. I have added the domain admins group to the local groups 'Hyper-V administrators' 'administrators' on the source and destination hosts. When I issue the command I get:

```
move-vm : You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'SourceHost'.
```

There are various articles out there about how to do this in 2012, however, its my understanding that the process has changed significantly in 2016 due to the depreciation of something called authorisation manager.

Does anyone have any experience on how to configure permissions to allow remote Hyper-V management with PowerShell specifically in 2016?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$cred

UserName                                     Password
--------                                     --------
PSAPIuser@domain.net System.Security.SecureString

move-vm : You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer
```

Comment: I think you do not use the credentials needed by defining `$username` as `.\PSAPIUser`. Use the domain name instead. Also, does the file `C:\key\PSAPIAUTH.txt` contain a plain text password?. Try what happens when you create the credentials using `Get-Credential`

Comment: Added the results above, still no joy. I can't seem to find anything anywhere on remote PowerShell administration of Hyper-v specifically with 2016. It's very annoying

Comment: Shot in the dark: Sometimes, using a UPN as username does not work while using the `domain\username` format does..

Comment: Ye, tried that and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Managing Hyper-V remotely uses something called Constrained Delegation. Imagine the scenario.

You are on the host Man1, and you are issuing a command to Hyp-001 to move a VM to Hyp-002. So you have Man1 issuing commands to Hyp-001, which is fine as it can use your credentials, but when Hyp-001 passes commands to Hyp-002 it has no credentials to pass, hence you get the error

```
move-vm : Virtual machine migration operation failed at migration source.
Failed to establish a connection with host 'ng2-vps-011.hyperslice.net': No credentials are available in the security package
```

to get around this you need to give specific permissions that allows hosts to run specific services on each other, within AD delegation.

From PowerShell it would look like this:

```
Set-ADObject -Identity $HostDeetsArra.Disname -ADD @{"msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo"="$service1/$Disname","$Service1/$HostName"} 
#$disnam = distignushed name, $Service1 is the service 'cifs' $hostanme is the FQDN
```

In 2016 you also need this:

```
Set-ADAccountControl -Identity $HostDeetsArra.Disname -TrustedToAuthForDelegation $true
```

My source for this information is below

https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/free-powershell-script-configure-constrained-delegation-hyper-v/

Comment: This is a massive topic, that you need to fully understand before you start changing things,  and its all covered in this article. I can can cut and paste but its going to be verbatim, and potentially dangerous.